# StackOverflowError in Knights Tour

Tags: java, stack-overflow, knights-tour

I have this Knight's Tour code but am getting a java.lang.StackOverflowError on line 37.  I'm not really sure where to go from here to fix it. I think the code in my main has something to do with it but I'm not sure what to do with it at this point. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main tour = new Main();
    tour.solveKnightTour();
}
private static int chessboard[][];
boolean a = true;
public Main() {
    chessboard = new int[8][8];
}
private void matrixChessBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d", chessboard[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
static boolean tour(int advance, int horizontal, int vertical, int xMove[], int yMove[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int moveHoriz = 0;
    int moveVert = 0;
    boolean a = true;
    chessboard[horizontal][vertical] = advance;
    if (advance == 63) {
        for (int t = 0; t < 8; t++) {
            for (int u = 0; u < 8; u++) {
                System.out.printf("%5d", chessboard[t][u]);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if ((horizontal + xMove[j] < 8 & (vertical + yMove[j]) >= 0 & (vertical + yMove[i]) < 8)
                    & (horizontal + xMove[i]) >= 0){
                if (chessboard[horizontal + xMove[i]][vertical + yMove[i]] == -1){
//line 37           if (tour(moveHoriz, moveVert, advance + 1, xMove, yMove)){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        a = false;
        chessboard[horizontal][vertical] = -1;
    }
    return a;
}
public boolean solveKnightTour() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            chessboard[x][y] = -1;
        }
    }
    int xMove[] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 };
    int yMove[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
    chessboard[0][0] = 0;
    if (!tour(0, 0, 1, xMove, yMove)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        matrixChessBoard();
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you traced through the code in your IDE debugger? That is the place to start.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code and isolate where the trouble is with your code. And when you post here and say *Line 37*, it helps a lot if you put a comment in your code on line 37, so we don't have to count lines.

Comment: sorry about that, I just updated it to show line 37.  I ran the debugger but it ultimately failed to respond. Under the Main at localhost, it says <not responding>

Comment: In your `tour()` method, you have a variable `i`, initialized to zero, and never changed.  What are you using it for?  Does that make sense to you?  What are `moveHoriz` and `moveVert` set to?  Where are they changed?   How are they used?  Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a stripped down version of your `tour()` method:

```
static boolean tour(int advance, int horizontal, int vertical, ...) {
    int moveHoriz = 0;
    int moveVert = 0;
    if (false) {
        ...
    } else {
        if (true)
            tour(moveHoriz, moveVert, advance + 1, ...);
    }
}
```

Called with `tour(0, 0, 1, ...)`, the function will enter with `advance=0`.  Various assignments will be done, various tests will be made, and then the `tour(moveHoriz, moveVert, advance+1, ...)` statement will be executed, which evaluates to the call `tour(0, 0, 1, ...)`.  Repeat until stack overflow.

- `moveHoriz` is passed to the `advance` parameter
- `moveVert` is passed to the `horizontal` parameter
- `advance+1` is passed to the `vertical` parameter

This is clearly not what you intended.  Since `advance+1` is not passed to `advance`, the `if (advance == 63)` condition will always evaluate to `false`, and you never break out of the recursion.